# Batch file to obtain system info of remote servers list with unique login credentials

Tags: batch, uptime

I'm not familiar with scripting. I have a task at hand which requires to check server uptimes to make sure if they were actually re-booted when they suppose to.

I was going through Google Search and have found an idea of an `input.txt` file, which contains all server names and `output.txt`, which contains the result.

The issue is that each server has a unique general login. e.g login name is `domain\server1`, password is `server1domain`. My input file is like:

```
domain\server1, server1domain
domain\server2, server2domain
domain\sevrer3, server3domain
```

I would like to use `serverinfo /s | find "uptime" >>c:\output.txt`, and `output.txt` I would like to be:

```
domain\server1      uptime   <uptime of server>
domain\server2      uptime   <uptime of server>
domain\server3      uptime   <uptime of server>
```

and so on until end of `input.txt` file.

Could someone create a very basic batch file?

Comment: Hi Ben! First, welcome to Super User! Please check out your formatting when you post. There's a preview window to show you how your question will look like. You need to check our [formatting help](http://superuser.com/editing-help). Could you maybe [edit] your question and show us what you already have and where specifically you're stuck? Don't forget to indent code by 4 spaces (or select it and press `Ctrl-K`).

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes, hope it would help. What I have at this time is a batch file which I tried to modify as per my environment:

I have an input.txt containing a list of my server names, where this loop is picking up server names line after line. At the same time I am trying to have unique login credentials within the script, this way I will not have to manually enter login credentials for them. Here is my script. The problem I am facing is that the login credentials are not getting passed as values when systeminfo.exe is executing.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (c:\Uptime\Input.txt) do (  
    echo %%a  
    set x=yellow  
    set login=%x%%%a  
    set pwd=%%a%x%  
    echo %login% pwd %pwd%  
    systeminfo /s %%a /u %login% /p %pwd% | find "System Up Time" >> c:\Uptime\A.txt  
    pause  
)
```

When I execute this batch file, I get the following:

```
C:\Uptime>(  
echo Server1  
 set x=yellow  
 set login=Server1 <- it should be: yellowServer1  
 set pwd=Server1  <- it should be: Server1yellow  
 echo  pwd <- not showing the values of variables from above, should be: yellowServer1 Server1yellow  
 systeminfo /s Server1 /u  /p    | find "System Up Time"  1>>c:\Uptime\A.txt  
 pause  
)  
Server1  
 pwd  
ERROR: Invalid Syntax. Value expected for '/u'.  
Type "SYSTEMINFO /?" for usage.  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am not sure why it is not taking the values from the variables in the systeminfo cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late for you but should be useful for anyone else looking for something similar, as I was recently...

You are not specifying the correct information in your command line.
Also The `systeminfo` command only has a boot time, not an uptime. That would create an empty file.

```
systeminfo /s Server1 /u %login%  /p %pwd%   | find "System Boot Time"  >> c:\Uptime\A.txt
```

You can use `cut` from `unixutils` to cleanup the file more.